# Multi dimensional Array merge in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Request your help, on how to merge multi dimensional associative array as below, tried the below function, and each one is giving different wrong output and the required output is as below ("Required Array). And Key "[Server]" name remains the same for all the arrays but with different values.

**Functions**

```
$output = array_merge(Array1,Array2,Array3);
$output = array_merge_recursive(Array1,Array2,Array3);
$output = array_replace_recursive(Array1,Array2,Array3);

foreach($Array1 as $a) { $output[$a["Server"]][] = $Count; }
foreach($Array2 as $b) { $output[$b["Server"]][] = $Rack; }
foreach($Array3 as $b) { $output[$b["Server"]][] = $Node; }
```

**Array1:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server1
            [Count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server2
            [Count] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server3
            [Count] => 4
        )
)
```

**Array2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server2
            [Rack] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server4
            [Rack] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server5
            [Rack] => 4
        )
)
```

**Array3:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server2
            [Node] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server5
            [Node] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server6
            [Node] => 4
        )
)
```

**Required Array Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server1
            [Count] => 1
            [Rack] => 0
            [Node] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server2
            [Count] => 4
            [Rack] => 1
            [Node] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server3
            [Count] => 4
            [Rack] => 0
            [Node] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server4
            [Count] => 0
            [Rack] => 4
            [Node] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server5
            [Count] => 0
            [Rack] => 4
            [Node] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Server] => Server6
            [Count] => 0
            [Rack] => 0
            [Node] => 4
        )
)
```

From,
Vino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index them by `Server` and then they will merge into the same key:

```
$output = array_merge(array_column($array1, null, 'Server'),
                      array_column($array2, null, 'Server'),
                      array_column($array3, null, 'Server'));
```

Not necessary, but if you want to get back to integer keys then:

```
$output = array_values($output);
```

To add missing keys you'll have to merge into a template array:

```
$keys = ['Server' => 0, 'Count' => 0, 'Rack' => 0, 'Node' => 0];

foreach($output as &$values) {
    $values = array_merge($keys, $values);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cadaver, Thank you for the help, the output generated by using your code is not same as expected , see above "Required Array Output"

Comment: Hi Cadaver,  The above code work perfectly if the "Server" values are different, if the Server value are same it just update as "0" rather than the correct values **Wrong Output** `[1] => Array ( [Server] => Server2  [Count] => 4  [Rack] => 1  [Node] => 1 )
[4] => Array ( [Server] => Server5  [Count] => 0  [Rack] => 4  [Node] => 4 )` **Correct Output** `[1] => Array ( [Server] => Server2  [Count] => 0  [Rack] => 0  [Node] => 1 ) 
[4] => Array ( [Server] => Server5  [Count] => 0  [Rack] => 0  [Node] => 4 ) `